# Eloquent multiple where with higher and lower then same value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I can't get results for the following Eloquent query:

```
return 
  Cost::where('zipcode_start', '>=', 8000)
  ->where('zipcode_end', '<=', 8000)
  ->pluck('price);
```

In that costs table I have some prices that depends on the range that a Zipcode that's given is in.

Comment: you can't find any data because you're  doing wrong. can you say more with one example

Comment: I think comparisons are wrong.

Comment: Does it work if you use whereRaw?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the query.. could you verify if it is really have data for that condition?

Comment: What type of column is `zipcode_start`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your comparisons should switch sides.

```
Cost::where([
    ['zipcode_start, '<=', 8000],
    ['zipcode_end', '>=', 8000]
])
->pluck('price');
```

Comment: Would not change anything Where A <= 8000 AND B >= 8000   would do the same as Where B >=8000 AND A <=8000

Comment: no no no. you haven't got it. My answer was change >= to <= . check carefully

Comment: If my answer is not clearly pointing it out, please help to improve it.

Comment: Alright my bet, but it still does not make sense... or his table columns are a bit messed up ;)

Comment: @Paolo_Mulder it does make sence ;-) this was the fix